# How to configure php_oci8 with php in linux?

Tags: php, oracle, redhat, oracle-call-interface

I have configured PHP5.5 in RHEL environment. I need to connect PHP5.5 with Oracle 11g which is installed in another server.

In my `php.ini` i have the `extension=php_oci8_11g.dll`. But what i need is dot(.) so for linux. So can anyone please help me how to configure/enable OCI8 with php?

Comment: Can anyone please tell me how will I install/configure OCI8 for PHP with out root access ???

Answer (score 0):

I ran in the same issue last year. You need to manually compile and install it.

Try following the section "Enabling the PHP OCI8 Extension on Linux" from [this site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/technote-php-instant-12c-2088811.html), you can skip the php install part of that is already done.

They will tell you to install oracle instant client, that can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html) (select your server type and afterwards be sure to download the version that is related to your 11g version)

Comment: Thank you for your information, but the problem i am facing is that I don't have root access permission in RHEL environment. So I can't use Yum or pecl commands . For that reason i am unable to configure OCI8 in php.

Comment: Then you will need to ask your system administrator to do the above steps for you.